How to fix the Single-Instance for my Wpf .NET 8 C# application?
I'm trying to bring up the hidden App when trying to reopen the app, it works when it's in a minimized state but it doesn't work when the window is in a hidden state!
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Adan
{
    public partial class App : System.Windows.Application
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

        const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
        const int SW_SHOW = 5;

        private static Mutex mutex;

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            bool createdNew;
            mutex = new Mutex(true, "AdanMutex", out createdNew);

            if (!createdNew)
            {
                IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, "أذان ليبيا");

                if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    // Check if the window is iconic (minimized)
                    if (IsIconic(handle))
                    {
                        ShowWindow(handle, SW_RESTORE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If window is not visible, show it
                        if (!IsWindowVisible(handle))
                        {
                            ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);
                        }
                    }

                    // Bring the window to the foreground
                    SetForegroundWindow(handle);
                }
                else
                {
                    ShowAlreadyRunningMessage();
                }

                Shutdown();
                return;
            }

            base.OnStartup(e);
        }

        private void ShowAlreadyRunningMessage()
        {
            Border border = new Border
            {
                Width = 300,
                Height = 100,
                CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(20),
                Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White,
                Child = new TextBlock
                {
                    Text = "البرنامج يعمل بالفعل",
                    FontSize = 16,
                    HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center
                }
            };

            Window messageWindow = new Window
            {
                Width = 300,
                Height = 100,
                WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen,
                WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
                AllowsTransparency = true,
                Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent,
                Content = border
            };
            messageWindow.Show();

            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer
            {
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)
            };
            timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
            {
                timer.Stop();
                messageWindow.Close();
            };
            timer.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mutex != null)
            {
                if (mutex.WaitOne(0))
                {
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                }
                mutex.Dispose();
            }

            base.OnExit(e);
        }
    }
}

So had tried everything but not worked to active or bring the hidden app
Does anyone have a solution to my problem or a complete library for Single Instance like what is available in .NET8

I don't understand.  Your app is running, but the main window is hidden and you want to show it?

@RobertHarvey yes the app is running but i make hide like most app workes in background processes and in notifyIcon,
but when trying to reopen the app frrom the exe should make it Active same app not that hidden not duplicated

Finally found a solution and it works fine
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace Adan
{
    // Partial application class in WPF
    public partial class App : System.Windows.Application
    {
        // Unique event name to avoid duplicate runs
        private const string UniqueEventName = "AdanAppEvent";
        // Unique Mutex name to ensure a single instance of the application
        private const string UniqueMutexName = "AdanAppMutex";
        private static Mutex _mutex = null;
        private static EventWaitHandle _eventWaitHandle;

        // Importing the SetForegroundWindow function from the user32.dll library
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        // Method called on startup
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            bool createdNew;
            _mutex = new Mutex(true, UniqueMutexName, out createdNew);
            _eventWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, UniqueEventName);

            if (createdNew)
            {
                base.OnStartup(e);

                Thread listenerThread = new Thread(ListenForShowWindowEvents);
                listenerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                listenerThread.IsBackground = true;
                listenerThread.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                _eventWaitHandle.Set();

                Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName))
                {
                    if (process.Id != current.Id)
                    {
                        SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Clean exit ensuring resources are freed
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_mutex != null)
            {
                _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                _mutex.Dispose();
            }

            // Ensure other resources are freed, if any
            base.OnExit(e);
        }

        // Thread listening for window show events
        private void ListenForShowWindowEvents()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                _eventWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    if (MainWindow != null)
                    {
                        if (MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
                        {
                            MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                        }
                        MainWindow.Activate();
                        MainWindow.Topmost = true;  // Temporarily bring the window to the foreground
                        MainWindow.Topmost = false; // Then set it back to false
                        MainWindow.Show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}


You have the right idea with the mutex, but there are things in there that you don't appear to need, like the timer.  Your fundamental problem seems to be that you appear to be interacting with the second instance of your program, and not the first.
Try something like this.  It uses System.Diagnostics.Process to communicate with the first instance:
using System.Diagnostics;

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    bool createdNew;
    mutex = new Mutex(true, "AdanMutex", out createdNew);

    if (!createdNew)
    {
        NotifyExistingInstance();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    base.OnStartup(e);
}

private void NotifyExistingInstance()
{
    var existingAppProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
    foreach (var process in existingAppProcess)
    {
        if (process.Id != Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
        {
            var hWnd = process.MainWindowHandle;
            if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

If it still doesn't work, break out your usual troubleshooting skills, like logging on the method entry and exit points of these methods to make sure they're actually executing.

Thanks but this method didn't work well it didn't show the hidden window only works with the minimized window but I solved the problem and it works well and fast in restore app window
